# iOS - key index from 3 strings

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am storing items in a large NSMutableArray.  3 strings define a unique item in this array. I'd like to have a NSMutableDictionary which maps the 3 string key to an entry in the array.

In my code the first 3 objects in item are the 3 strings which define a unique item. How can I most efficiently create the key to do the lookup? I'm guessing stringWithFormat isn't the best idea. I'm trying to speed up a large amount of lookups that occur.

```
- (void)addItem:(NSArray*)item {
    // create entry from item
    [mEntries addObject:entry]; 
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [item objectAtIndex:0],
                               [item objectAtIndex:1],[item objectAtIndex:2]];
    [mEntryMap setObject:entry forKey:key];
}

- (Entry*)getItem:(NSArray*)strs {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [strs objectAtIndex:0],
                               [strs objectAtIndex:1],[strs objectAtIndex:2]];
    return [mEntryMap objectForKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create string directly from array no need to use long method

```
- (void)addItem:(NSArray*)item {
    // create entry from item
    [mEntries addObject:entry]; 
    NSString *key=[item componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    [mEntryMap setObject:entry forKey:key];
}

- (Entry*)getItem:(NSArray*)strs {
    NSString *key=[strs componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [mEntryMap objectForKey:key];
}
```